# Spring boot. Map request to object if field isnt there

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, object, get-mapping

Suppose I make a get request to foo() with the JSON body:

```
{
    „a“: „hallo“,
    „b“: „world“,
    „aa“: 10
}
```

```
    @PostMapping("/foo")
    public void foo(@RequestBody MyClass myClass) {
        //do stuff
    }
```

```
class MyClass {
  
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;
    int aa;

}
```

If the JSON object and the class match, then it works fine and you get a MyClass object with the correct variables set. But now I want to set only those fields in the MyClass class that I have also passed and the rest is initialized with null. How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you use '@RequestBody' with '@GetMapping'? Shouldnt it be '@PostMapping' or some else HTTP method which takes a RequestBody?

Comment: Jackson has annotations that will ignore unknown fields when parsing from json to obj

Answer (score 0):

you have to change @GetMapping to @PostMapping if you want to use @RequestBody.

-Greetings :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for correction. But That wasnt really my problem. More the mapping from json to the Java-Object

Comment: Oh ok, try to add @Data anotation, that will add the getters and setters to your class

Comment: And did you add @RequestMapping in your controller class?